# Pandemic Outbreak Calculator

Tags: code-golf, graph-theory, board-game

In the board game Pandemic, an **outbreak** occurs when a city contains more than 3 disease cubes. When the outbreak occurs, any disease cubes in the city in excess of 3 are removed, and each city connected to it gains one disease cube. This means that chain reactions can, and will occur.

**Important note: Each city may only outbreak once in each chain reaction.**

### Input

A list of cities each containing:

- An integer representing the number of disease cubes .
- And a number of identifiers of the form (A, B ... AA, AB) (lowercase is allowed) representing which cites in list order it is connected to.

### Output

A list of integers representing the number of disease cubes in each city after outbreaks have been resolved.

### Winning Condition

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in bytes wins.

Comment: Could you add test cases?

Comment: I think it's clear enough.

Comment: Are city edges bidirectional? Is it strictly greater than (that is, a pandemic starts upon a city gaining its fourth cube)?

Comment: The point isn't that it's clear enough (which it isn't); test cases are to test people's solutions otherwise it's very inconvenient to verify that one's solution is valid.

Comment: it would take time

Comment: and yes to both of those questions

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/94869/discussion-between-hyperneutrino-and-who).

Comment: `A list of integers` is a string of integers separated by something other than a digit (whitespace, newline, etc.) ok?

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 201 bytes

```python
f=lambda d,e,v=[],n=enumerate:any((D>3)>(i in v)for i,D in n(d))and f([(i in v)and D or(min(3,D)+sum((k not in v)*(d[k]>3)for k in E))for i,(D,E) in n(zip(d,e))],e,v+[i for i,D in n(d)if D>3])or sum(d)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY6xDoMwDER/xaNdPJTSqRJM4SuiDKkCakQxKAUk@vM0EVSVOtl3tt7duE6PQYpta8un7e/OguOGl1IblrKRuW@CnZqblRVRVQVV6MELLNQOATyrJAQdkRUHLervOUkFQ8DeCxasKHvNPWIHMkz7xwmd7kxEJlKXvJoOKiquaSe//YixEZFJtTLt4S/YtxB7GYpuSnC0jcHLhLHLlaFguBgGrfNjOf9mbgzR9gE)

Worst case O(n) on the number of cities. `d` is a list of disease counts, `e` is a list of city connections by `0`-indexed position corresponding to `d`, and `v` is the visited array (which should not be given as input, obviously).

For the case `[4, 3, 2]` with connections `0 <-> 1`, `1 <-> 2`, and `0 <-> 2`, first, city `0` outbreaks and becomes `3` and sets city `1` to `4` and city `2` to `3`. Then, city `1` outbreaks and becomes `3` and sets city `2` to `4` (city `0` already had an outbreak). Finally, city `2` has an outbreak and nothing can be affected, leaving all three cities on `3` disease cubes, totalling `9`.